# custom query for datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am currently building an application in C#. In this application, people give values in a label and ​​that values will be saved in a database. This also works at the moment. What I want is the following:

The people can see their own values back in a datagridview. If I do this with the wizard of the datagridview I can't select label2.Text(this is the customerID).

The query I used below is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM prestaties WHERE gebruikerid = '" + label1.Text + "'";
```

But it doesn't work. I don't see anything in my datagrid.

Sorry for my bad English. I hope you can understand me.

The code below I already have, but it doesn't work

---

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using System.Data.OleDb;

    namespace Eindopdracht
    {
        public partial class resultaten : Form
        {
            public resultaten()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                dataGridView1.Show();

                           }


            private string username;

            public void displaydata(String ddata)
            {

                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"provider= microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\\Users\\Jeffrey\\Desktop\\Eindopdracht WOE\\Eindopdracht\\sample.mdb");
                string select = "SELECT * FROM prestaties WHERE gebruikerid = '" + label2.Text + "'";

                conn.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(select, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.tables[0];
                conn.Close();
            }





              public void setUsername(String name)
            {
                username = name;

                label1.Text = username;
                setID();
            }

            public void setID()
            {
                OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(@"provider= microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\\Users\\Jeffrey\\Desktop\\Eindopdracht WOE\\Eindopdracht\\sample.mdb");
                string selectie = "SELECT id FROM inlog WHERE Username='" + label1.Text + "'";

                OleDbCommand vcom1 = new OleDbCommand(selectie, vcon);
                vcon.Open();
                vcom1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OleDbDataReader dr = null;
                dr = vcom1.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var waarde = dr.GetValue(0);
                    label2.Text = waarde.ToString();


                }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You commented out this line: `//dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.tables[0];`.  Side note: SQL Injection, use parameters.  Instead of querying the database, you can use a DataView instead.

Comment: Yes I commented that line out because it doesn't also work with that line.

Comment: Now I don't see where you are calling `displayData`.

Comment: Where is the code that updates the table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my code is 100% correct. I've build this by myself. If I use the class `displayData` in the begin next to `InitializeComponent();` I will get an error.